# Attribute Byte to change display color

Tags: c

I’m trying to change the attribute byte to allow a white text and a blue background, I currently have 0x07 light grey on black. I can get blue background, but not white text. I’ve tried 1x15 1x15f and neither work. Any feedback or links resources would be appreciated.

```
void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "my first kernel";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins here.
    unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int j = 0;

/* this loops clears the screen
* there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
    /* blank character */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
    /* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;         
        j = j + 2;
    }
```

Comment: what is this for?  what kind of device?

Comment: VirtualMachine of Ubuntu 18.04